# Multiple parameters with one onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

I have my search bar below. When I press the 'search' button, I want it to update results but also redirect to a different page.

```
function SearchBar(props) { 
    const [innerSearch, setInnerSearch] = useState(""); 
    return ( 
      <div > 
        <input 
          aria-labelledby="search-button" 
          name="search" 
          id="search" 
          type="search" 
          value={innerSearch}
          onChange={e => setInnerSearch(e.target.value)}
        />  
        <button 
          id="search-button" 
          type="button" 
          onClick={() => props.onSubmit(innerSearch)} >
          Search 
        </button> 
      </div> 
    ); 
  } 
};
```

```
let navigate = useNavigate(); 
const routeChange = () =>{ 
  let path = `/Home`; 
  navigate(path);
}
```

I want to somehow have this routeChange below in that same button while it also searches if that's even possible.

```
onClick={routeChange}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `onClick()` function needs to call a "wrapper" function that contains both your `onSubmit()` prop function and the route change function.

For example:

```
let navigate = useNavigate(); 
const routeChange = () =>{ 
  let path = `/Home`; 
  navigate(path);
}

const wrapperFunction = () => {
  routeChange();
  props.onSubmit(innerSearch)
}
```

```
onClick={wrapperFunction}
```